# JavaMail smtp.gmail.com ANT vs Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have a very frustrating issue with code that's trying to send an email through JavaMail via gmail. My code works when run from Eclipse, but when I run through Ant it fails to connect with a "Could not connect to SMTP host, reponse -1" error.

I'm using the same JRE's in both Eclipse and Ant and don't see anything from a classpath perspective that is different.

The JavaMail debug logs are below - first the successful run from within Eclipse;

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
Email Recipients = <email removed>
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP b14sm9639869itd.15 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465
```

...and now the failed run from Ant;

```
   [java] Emailing skip report...
     [java] DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.2
     [java] DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
     [java] DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
     [java] DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
     [java] DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
     [java] DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
     [java] Email Recipients = <email address hidden>
     [java] DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
     [java] DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
     [java] DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
     [java] DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
     [java] javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
     [java]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1533)
     [java]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:453)
     [java]     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
     [java]     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
     [java]     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
     [java]     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
     [java]     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
     [java]     at com.diona.skipped.record.EmailReport.sendReportEmail(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at com.diona.skipped.record.SkipAlert.processLogs(Unknown DEBUG SMTP: EOF: [EOF]
     [java] DEBUG SMTP: could not connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465, response: -1
```

Any ideas?

Chris

Comment: Is your workstation behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running from ant on the same machine as when you run from Eclipse?  The JavaMail FAQ has [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).  Also, you're using a very old version of JavaMail; upgrade if you can to the current version 1.5.5.